# TestData doesn't work when try to filtering? React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I trying to filter all users. First check my code:

```
  const
```

I got errro message ->

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'filteredUsers')

What's going on here?

i don't use the filteredUsers variable anywhere in the code

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything from the selector, since you've wrapped the filter with curly brackets, and no return statement. Remove the curlies.

In addition, the selector is creating a new array, and not an object with the property `filteredUsers`. Remove the destructuring assignment.

```
const filteredUsers = useSelector(({ organisationUsers }) =>
  organisationUsers.users.filter(user => selectedUsers?.includes(user.uuid))
);
```